# Changing object mutability using shallow/deep copy

Tags: python

I am trying to play around with normal copy (assignment), shallow copy and deep copy concepts for mutable and immutable types.

List is mutable - so when assigned to another object, any append (or value change using index value) to the other object will impact the original object. An assignment to the new object will not impact the original object.

String is immutable - so when assigned to another object, any change to the other object be it modification or assignment will not impact the original object.

I was wondering if shallow copy concept can be used to make string behavior mutable and list immutable. From the below experiment I notice that shallow/deep copy on a string object (immutable) does not impact its immutable behaviour. Where as shallow/deep copy of list object (mutable) makes it immutable.

Please can you shed some light on this.

```
 import copy

    print('----------LIST BEHAVIOUR - MUTABLE----------')

    l1=[1,2,3]
    print(l1)
    l2=l1
    print(l2)
    l2[2]=10
    l2.append(22)
    print(l2)
    print(l1)

    print('----------LIST SHALLOW COPY----------')

    l1=[1,2,3]
    print(l1)
    l2=copy.copy(l1)
    print(l2)
    l2[2]=10
    l2.append(22)
    print(l2)
    print(l1)

    print('----------LIST DEEP COPY----------')

    l1=[1,2,3]
    print(l1)
    l2=copy.deepcopy(l1)
    print(l2)
    l2[2]=10
    l2.append(22)
    print(l2)
    print(l1)

    print('----------STRING BEHAVIOUR - IMMUTABLE----------')

    str1='abc'
    print(str1)
    str2=str1
    print(str2)
    str2='xyz'
    print(str2)
    print(str1)

    print('----------STRING SHALLOW COPY----------')

    str1='abc'
    print(str1)
    str2=copy.copy(str1)
    print(str2)
    str2='xyz'
    print(str2)
    print(str1)

    print('----------STRING DEEP COPY----------')

    str1='abc'
    print(str1)
    str2=copy.copy(str1)
    print(str2)
    str2='xyz'
    print(str2)
    print(str1)
```

Output:

```
----------LIST BEHAVIOUR - MUTABLE----------
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 10, 22]
[1, 2, 10, 22]
----------LIST SHALLOW COPY----------
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 10, 22]
[1, 2, 3]
----------LIST DEEP COPY----------
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 10, 22]
[1, 2, 3]
----------STRING BEHAVIOUR - IMMUTABLE----------
abc
abc
xyz
abc
----------STRING SHALLOW COPY----------
abc
abc
xyz
abc
----------STRING DEEP COPY----------
abc
abc
xyz
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a copy of list you are creating new list and changing it does not change the original list. You did not make it immutable, you just created a new list.

Because string is immutable, creating a copy is same as assigning it. In both cases a new string is created. You can not make it mutable.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work as you think. Copy is copy, that's all. Shallow copy means just copy the elements in the current container. While deep copy means recursively copy all possible elements in nested containers.

And assign is changing reference. While changing the reference of value types and string, a copy will be created.